# SQL Server - How to filter data based on data combination from two or more columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was trying to filter out data in the dashboard based on two fields, for example, product category and year.

I have data where some products are sold in 2007, 2008, and 2009, while others are sold only in 2008. I want to exclude data where sale data for products with only 2008 year as the sale year.

For example,

| BrandName | Year |
| --- | --- |
| Toys | 2008 |
| Footwear | 2008 |
| Cookware | 2008 |
| Toys | 2009 |
| Toys | 2007 |
| Footwear | 2009 |
| Footwear | 2007 |
| Clothes | 2008 |

Expected output:

| BrandName | Year |
| --- | --- |
| Toys | 2008 |
| Footwear | 2008 |
| Toys | 2009 |
| Toys | 2007 |
| Footwear | 2009 |
| Footwear | 2007 |

I tried following SQL but does not seem to work

```
Select BrandName, Concat(BrandName,Year(UpdateDate)), SOUNDEX(Concat(BrandName,Year(UpdateDate))) as Data from Dbo.DimProduct
Group by BrandName, Concat(BrandName,Year(UpdateDate))
having Count(SOUNDEX(Concat(BrandName,Year(UpdateDate)))) > 1
Order by SOUNDEX(Concat(BrandName,Year(UpdateDate)))
```

Basically, if there is only one record like Clothes2008 and Cookware2008, exclude them from the resultset.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: `HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN UpdateDate < '20090101' OR UpdateDate >= '20100101' THEN 1 END) > 0` also what's with all those weird `CONCAT` and `SOUNDEX` functions they appear unnecessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, ProductCategory VARCHAR(30), _year CHAR(4));
INSERT INTO @tbl (ProductCategory, _year) VALUES
('Toys', '2008'),
('Footwear', '2008'),
('Cookware', '2008'),
('Toys', '2009'),
('Toys', '2007'),
('Footwear', '2009'),
('Footwear', '2007'),
('Clothes', '2008');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT * 
       , total_count = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ProductCategory ORDER BY ProductCategory)
       , _2008_count = SUM(IIF (_year='2008', 1, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY ProductCategory ORDER BY ProductCategory)
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT ID, ProductCategory, _year 
FROM rs
WHERE total_count <> _2008_count
ORDER BY ID;
```

**Output**

```
+----+-----------------+-------+
| ID | ProductCategory | _year |
+----+-----------------+-------+
|  1 | Toys            |  2008 |
|  2 | Footwear        |  2008 |
|  4 | Toys            |  2009 |
|  5 | Toys            |  2007 |
|  6 | Footwear        |  2009 |
|  7 | Footwear        |  2007 |
+----+-----------------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks @Yitzhak Khabinsky.
Following sql worked for me.
`

Comment: `;With RS AS(  
Select *  
   , total_count = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY BrandName ORDER BY BrandName)  
   , _2008_count = SUM(IIF (Year(UpdateDate)='2008', 1, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY BrandName ORDER BY BrandName)  
   , _2009_count = SUM(IIF (Year(UpdateDate)='2009', 1, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY BrandName ORDER BY BrandName)  
   , _2007_count = SUM(IIF (Year(UpdateDate)='2007', 1, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY BrandName ORDER BY BrandName)  
from dbo.DimProduct   
)  
SELECT distinct BrandName, Year(UpdateDate)  
FROM RS  
Where _2008_count <> 0 AND _2009_count <> 0 AND _2009_count <> 0`